# include validation service in codeigniter4 failed

Tags: codeigniter-4

i try to make my first form validation in codeigniter4.For that i've create a controller with a function to check the post-vars. At the beginning, ci4 need to load the libary, so i do it like in the docu

```
$validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
```

For this i recieve the following error.

```
...
message "Class 'Myth\\Auth\\Authentication\\Passwords\\ValidationRules' not found"
file    "mypath/system/Validation/Validation.php"
function    "loadRuleSets"
class   "CodeIgniter\\Validation\\Validation"
function    "run"
class   "CodeIgniter\\Validation\\Validation"
....
```

What i do wrong, or is there something to setup for a new project before it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg

i've found the problem. in the app/config autoload.php and validation.php was a class "Myth" wich is not in use. SO i commet it out and the thinks works fine.